# Cocos2D JS Vec2 is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-js

I've been trying to use Vec2 for a while with no luck, I got error message such as Vec2 is undefined, Vec2 is not a function, etc.
Code I've tried:

`var point = Vec2(100,100);`
`var point = cc.math.Vec2(100,100);`

Is there anything else I'm missing? It seems that the documentation for Cocos2D JS is not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Vec2 in js so I do not know explicitly what is happening with that but you can use cc.p(x,y)

Example:

var point = cc.p(100, 100);
cc.log(point.x) -> 100

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
var v = new cc.math.Vec2(x,y);
```